# NetUserChangePassword() can set a password to Administrator?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, administrator

When you enable Administrator user to login, the password is empty by default. At least on Windows 10, if you want login in a remote computer (via RDP) with Administrator user, must set a password before.

[`NetUserChangePassword()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserchangepassword) will be successful to this? considering that usually remote computer have only 2 users (already including Administrator), then my application is executed on second user >>

[image]

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT, thank you very much. Worked with `NetUserSetInfo` (and not isneed know old password like `NetUserChangePassword`)!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [NetUserSetInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusersetinfo) to set the administrator password locally.

> Members of the Administrators local group can set any modifiable user
> account elements. All users can set the usri2_country_code member of
> the USER_INFO_2 structure (and the usri1024_country_code member of the
> USER_INFO_1024 structure) for their own accounts.